# How to Create New Project in FireBase using .net Mvc

Tags: firebase, .net-core, model-view-controller

I want to create a new project in Firebase and create new android App and download there google-service.json file. Everything Using programmatically. I tried to login with third party credentials after that what to do understand.

Can this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase has a REST API for creating and managing projects. Since it's REST based, it can be called from any platform that can make HTTP calls (including .NET).

For more information on this API, see the [documentation for the Firebase Management API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/).